# How can I select all checkBoxes at once in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I've got a recyclerView with checkBoxes and I want to select all of them at once by pressing a button

I've try this so far...

This is the Adapter -

class AdapterNfs (context: MainActivity, private val listener: OnItemClickListener) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterNfs.NfViewHolder>() {

```
private val context: Context
private var list = emptyList<ReceiverPayment>()
private var status: Boolean = false

init {
    this.context = context
}

fun setAllChecked(isChecked: Boolean){
    status = isChecked
    Log.d("***log", status.toString())
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NfViewHolder {
    val binding = ItemNotasFiscaisBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    return NfViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NfViewHolder, position: Int){
    holder.binding.apply {
        textNFnumber.text = list[position].id
        textNFvalue.text = list[position].totalValue
        nfStatus.text = list[position].paid.toString()
    }
    holder.binding.checkBoxNf.isChecked = status
}

override fun getItemCount() = list.size

inner class NfViewHolder(var binding: ItemNotasFiscaisBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), View.OnClickListener{

    init{
        binding.checkBoxNf.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

   override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        val checkbox = view as CheckBox
        val position : Int = adapterPosition
        val data = list
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
             listener.onItemClick(position, checkbox.isChecked, data)
        }
   }
}

fun setData(newList: List<ReceiverPayment>) {
    val nfDiffUtil = DiffUtilGeneric(list, newList)
    val nfResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(nfDiffUtil)
    this.list = newList
    nfResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
}

interface OnItemClickListener {
    fun onItemClick(
        position: Int,
        checked: Boolean,
        data: List<ReceiverPayment>
    )
}
```

}

and this is the Main -

class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity(), AdapterNfs.OnItemClickListener {

```
private val myAdapter = AdapterNfs(this, this)
private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

private var valueTotal = 00.00

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    mainViewModel = MainViewModel()

    setupRecyclerView()
    getAllNfs()
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.selectAllCheckBoxes.setOnClickListener {
        setAllCheckBoxes(true)
    }
}

override fun onItemClick(position: Int, checked: Boolean, data: List<ReceiverPayment>) {
    val totalValueSelected = binding.totalValue
    val nfSelected = data[position].totalValue.toString().toDouble()

    if (checked) {
        valueTotal += nfSelected
        totalValueSelected.text = valueTotal.toString()
    } else {
        valueTotal -= nfSelected
        totalValueSelected.text = valueTotal.toString()
    }
}

private fun setupRecyclerView(){
    recyclerView = binding.recyclerViewNfs
    binding.recyclerViewNfs.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    binding.recyclerViewNfs.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    binding.recyclerViewNfs.addItemDecoration(
        DividerItemDecoration(
            this,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
        )
    )

    binding.recyclerViewNfs.adapter = myAdapter
}

private fun getAllNfs(){
    mainViewModel.allNfs.observe(this@MainActivity){response ->
        response.let {
            myAdapter.setData(it[0].receiverPayments as List<ReceiverPayment>)
        }
    }
}

private fun setAllCheckBoxes(isChecked: Boolean){
    myAdapter.setAllChecked(isChecked)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter , call notifyDataSetChanged() after change the status

```
fun setAllChecked(isChecked: Boolean){
status = isChecked
Log.d("***log", status.toString())
notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```